# Dynamic content without multiple pages

Tags: php, dynamic-content

Let me start by saying i am new to mysql and php, and I'm sure this is a noob question but I've been searching google and can't find any solution.

Basically I want to create 1 template file that will read all of a table from a database with multiple rows and columns but only display one row at a time.

An example would be http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp scroll towards the bottom where it shows peter griffen and glen quagmire i would want it to only display 'glen quagmire' or only display 'peter griffen' depending on which link was previously clicked.

would i need to somehow assign an ID to the link url so php knew which row to parse etc.. ?

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way is to use the query string.  Make the link `<a href='stuff.php?id=1'>View #1</a>`.  Then use a `where id='$id'` clause in the SQL query, setting `$id` equal to the query string parameter `$_GET['id']`.